# Ambiguous expansion of macro 'NSLocalizedString'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nslocalizedstring

I have a static library in my project which has a prefix file inside the folder. both the project prefix as well as static library prefix files have an entry like below.

```
#undef NSLocalizedString
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) \
[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:TABLE(@"Strings")] "
```

before using Xcode 8 everything was working fine. now im getting error as

> Ambiguous expansion of macro 'NSLocalizedString' many places where NSlocalizedString is used.

I think its because of declaring NslocalizedString in two files.
But how to solve this error.

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635624/xcode-8-ambiguous-expansion-of-macro-nslocalizedstring